# Accessing Google Drive via KDE Online Accounts?

Tags: kde, online-accounts

In system settings there is Online Accounts. I made an account through this GUI interface using my existing Google account, and the creation seemed to be confirmed by a two-factor authentication. The confirmation involved logging onto my Google account and confirming different types of access, including access to Google Drive. I accepted that access. But now I want to actually access Google Drive locally I don't see how to do that.

Locally I only see YouTube Access, even though I accepted access to more services than that (including GDrive).

[image]

I don't see anything relevant if I use the main search:

[image]

And the sidebar of Dolphin doesn't show anything new, nor is there a new folder at root or home.

How am I supposed to access GDrive locally?

---

Update: I installed kio-gdrive by running `sudo apt-get install kio-gdrive`. This seems to have added the option to include GDrive access into the Online Accounts list. I still do not see a way to access the account locally (via the GUI or bash).

[image]

Comment: Make sure that you have kio-gdrive installed.

Comment: After I installed kio-gdrive, my Google Drive showed up under Network in Dolphin.